# Qual a diferença entre setAttribute() e setAttributeNode()?

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia tirar essa dúvida? Preciso saber qual a diferença entre setAttribute() e setAttributeNode()?

Grata!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas tem a mesma função: criar (ou alterar) um atributo no elemento e setar um valor. Só muda a forma de construção (caso o atributo já exista, será TODO substituído pelo valor setado):

**setAttribute:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("name", "teste"); // crio/altero o atributo name="teste" no input
```

**setAttributeNode:**

```
var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var atributo = document.createAttribute("name");
atributo.value = "teste";
elemento.setAttributeNode(atributo);  // crio/altero o atributo name="teste" no input
```